# UK visitor visa for spouse - How to show proof of ties

Tags: uk, proof-of-ties

I am a British citizen who has lived in the U.K. for 15 years. I applied for a visitor visa for my spouse, but they refused it because they want some evidence to prove she would return back to her country. She is a housewife.

What evidence can I give them?

Answer (score 10):

Understandably when granting a visa to someones partner they want proof that person will not simply remain in the UK to be with said partner.

Examples of proof of ties to home country include:

- **Employment/Business ownership** - Vacation approval from management, letter from employer to prove employment, pay slips
- **Home ownership/Rent** - Showing a lease agreement or house deed can help to show the intention to return and continue living in said house/apartment (But note, this alone does not prove intent as you can simply rent out a property from overseas)
- **School/University** - If a student proof of enrolment, letters from the Uni, payment details for the classes can show intent to return home to complete the education, especially if already paid for
- **Strong family ties** - if a carer for a family member, a parent to young children, or an elder sibling that provides for family members, this can also indicate returning when used in combination of other things, as again you could simply send money back home
- **Benefits given at home** - any housing, social, parental benefits paid by the home government could show indication for returning home for them to continue
- **Community engagement** - strong links to the community itself such as church groups, volunteering, teaching etc
- **Professional license** - any license which must be renewed in their home country, or requires constant use

If none of the above are possible, and can not be made possible, then consulting an immigration attorney may be beneficial