# my visitor visa rejected for Canada , why it happen and what i need to do to get it?

Tags: visas, canada, visa-refusals, proof-of-ties

My name is shiva and I am 31 and single. I live in Iran and recently I got my refusal letter for a visitor visa from Canada.

I work in a company which represents an international brand. I have a high position and I provided 6 payslips with high payments. I have recently had a promotion which is shown in my payslip. I had a letter that said I have 2 weeks off from my company to visit Canada and I must come back after these days.

My bank account is good enough but I do not own any house or property and I live with my parents. All my family (parents and siblings) live in Iran and I said this in my cover letter.

My travel history was good enough and two years ago I had a Schengen Visa.
My invitation letter was from my cousin who is married to a Canadian. They said in that letter that they will be my host for 2 weeks and they have been advised and verily believe that my financial status is such that I am comfortably able to pay my expenses without any assistance and verily believe that I will not overstay.

My rejection reasons are:

1. Family ties in Canada and in Iran
2. Purpose of visit

My question is why I got rejected and what can I do about it?

Comment: They doubt your intention to leave at the end of your visit. Having family in Canada seems to be a minus in your case therefore you’d need to do something to offset the immigration risk assessment eg broader travel history, marriage/family, property. Where have you travelled to previously?

Comment: You can appeal and reapply, if you do you have to provide more evidence and a stronger argument that you will return after those two weeks,  I wrote a list of some more examples of points you can make to prove ties to your country here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/124915/uk-visitor-visa-for-spouse-how-to-show-proof-of-ties/

Comment: I have been to Europe two times. the first trip was 10 years ago to Germany, Netherland, Belgium, and the second trip was 2 years ago to France, Spain, and Sweden. Also, I have been to Turkey, Emarate, Azarbayjan too. I am single but if I said that I have a fiance would it be helpful? and then what should i provide to help me with this matter?

Comment: @Uciebila I got a strong letter from my company that I have a high position and I need to come back after two weeks. I do not have any property. only a car. maybe I can say that I have a fiance which I had before but what I need to show them as proof and would it be helpful?

Comment: @ShivaT is there anything else from the list provided that is applicable to you besides the employment letter? Anything that shows strong ties to your country or community, anything that proves at all you wouldn't simply just stay there and live off the money in your account for a while?

Comment: @Uciebila Maybe I can say my father has a problem with his heart, providing some medical documents, and we are so close so I need to stay with them?? Also, I had an admission to Europe 10 years ago for studying master with fund, but I decided to stay in Iran. it is not helpful.right?

Comment: @Shiva T Be careful about re-applying very quickly with new evidence of ties to home that you didn’t mention in your first application.